# MessageDlg button language is not the OS language

Tags: c++, delphi, vcl

Depending on the installed RAD Studio language version, the `MessageDlg()` button titles are represented in the appropriate installation language instead of the OS language.

Is there a chance to replace specific files of the installed version with files of another version in another language? Does anybody know which files of the VCL (?) might need to get replaced?

Or, is the only chance to reinstall RAD Studio in the new language?

Comment: Why not stick to task dialogs instead?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, might be an alternative in the future, but I would like to know, technically, which files are responsible for the MessageDlg language, and could be replaced with a version in another language.

Comment: BdsSetLang.exe lets you select the IDE language and the library language separately. If you installed all Delphi languages you can select between English, French, German and Japanese.

Comment: There is no “XE10“. XE8 was the last, then the “XE“ part was dropped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me toward BdsSetLang.exe, didn't know about it. Also thanks for clarification about the XE prefix.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand internally, `MessageDlg()` uses a Task Dialog when running on Vista+, `UseLatestCommonDialogs` is true, ComCtrl32 v6 Visual Styles are enabled, and VCL Styles are not used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know, and that makes it more acceptable to use `MessageDlg` IMO. Still, I don't really see why you (today) would use it instead of using task dialogs explicitly. For instance, `MessageDlg` don't let you use the "Main Instruction" font, does it? Or [custom button texts](https://privat.rejbrand.se/rterestoresettings.png).